# EF 6 disable save related entities (virtual)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have a problem in my application using Entity Framework 6

One of my EF Entities is:

```
public class EmployeeHoliday
    {
        public EmployeeHoliday()
        {
            this.Employee = new Model.Employee();
        }

        public int HolidayId { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public byte HolidayTypeId { get; set; }
        public string MasterEntity { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public bool NonContinuous { get; set; }
        public bool RequestInAdvance { get; set; }
        public bool Authorized { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AuthorizedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AuthorizedDate { get; set; }
        public string AuthorizedNotes { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> DaysPending { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DaysUsed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DaysApproved { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

This entity has a relation to `Employee` EF Entity but I don't load it in all cases.

Right now I'm trying to insert a new `EmployeeHoliday` and I get an error, looking at the Entity Framework Log (in the console) I can see that is trying to update `Employee`.

Here is what Im doing:

```
// insert
                var newRequest = new Model.EmployeeHoliday();

                newRequest.EmployeeId = request.EmployeeId;
                newRequest.MasterEntity = Uow.MasterEntity;
                newRequest.CreatedBy = Uow.UserId;
                newRequest.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                newRequest.Authorized = false;
                newRequest.HolidayTypeId = request.HolidayTypeId;
                newRequest.RequestDate = request.RequestDate;
                newRequest.NonContinuous = !continuousDays;
                newRequest.StartDate = dates.FirstOrDefault();
                newRequest.EndDate = dates.LastOrDefault();
                newRequest.RequestInAdvance = request.RequestInAdvance;
                newRequest.IsActive = true;

Uow.HolidayRepository.Add(newRequest);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The Console Log:

```
INSERT [dbo].[employee]([employerid], [memberid], [masterentity], [joindate], [employeenumber], [employeeformat], [leavedate], [leavetype], [credentialnumber], [employeetypeid], [employeegroupid], [jobtitleid], [profitcenterid], [locationid], [shiftcode], [timepolicyid], [holidaypolicyid], [overtimepolicyid], [supervisorid], [holidaytemplateid], [patterncode], [ispunishable], [isactive])
VALUES (@0, @1, NULL, @2, @3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @4, @5, @6, @7, NULL, @8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @9, @10)
SELECT [employeeid]
FROM [dbo].[employee]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [employeeid] = scope_identity()
```

> > I'm not inserting an `Employee`, I'm inserting a `EmployeeHoliday`

So, the error of course is:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'masterentity', table 'dbo.employee'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

> Any clue I can tell EF to not save my related entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating new `EmployeeHoliday`, you also create `Employee` instance in the constructor.

Try to make it null and see if it works.

```
newRequest.EmployeeId = request.EmployeeId;
newRequest.Employee = null;
```